# ffmpeg, making gif or video, how to make the "PLAY" faster, fps=1 dont work

Tags: ffmpeg, conversion, jpeg, gif, framerate

i have this problem, i download a gif, i extract all the jpgs from it, i modified the jpg, then i was trying to recreate the gif using the new jpgs, but i found that whatever i try, no matter if is a software or ffmpeg, my gif play far slowly that the original gif.

i try several softwares, some options say, "interval", "frame delay", "animation delay time" i try the lowerest number in all these softwares, and the result is never the same as the original gif.

then i find ffmpeg, and i like it, but even in my research i still cannot find the correct setting to make my gif or clip as the original one. should be not difference, rigth?, the original gif have a timeplay of 44 seconds, i dont deleted or added new jpegs to the ones extracted. the original gif send me 2100 and that is the same number i use. and the best result i have till now is 01 minute 28 sec.

the options, "-vf fps=1", "-r 1", -framerate 1" and "-framerate 1/1" is not the correct ones?????

can someone tell me what option i need to add to make faster the playtime of the gif or clip???

i want to use these jpgs to make a clip (webm or mp4) but also dont mind if only can make as a gif.

thanks for your help.

Comment: 1st google hit: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To play 2100 JPGs in 44 seconds, you'll need a framerate of around 50, so.

```
ffmpeg -framerate 50 -i img%d.jpg -pix_fmt yuv420p video.mp4
```

Comment: thanks friend, im new in this, and i dont understand how works a lot of the settings, i try using, 1,2,5,10,30,60,100,FPS, and never work. now i will search for the settings for make the clip retain the colors of the original jpgs, the problem of the timeplay is solved but now the final clip lost the color. anyway thanks.

Comment: trying version 5 of ffmpeg I get `Option framerate not found.`

Comment: Add -report and rerun. Share link to report.